# getting row id from sqlite using other fields as where condition

Tags: android, sqlite, rowid

sir, how can i return the rowid of my database depending on the inputs name, number? this code just return the value 0 everytime. my primary key is KEY_ROWID. thanks for help in advance

```
//get rowid
public long getRowId(String name, String number) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_NUMBER};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NUMBER+ "=" +number, null, null, null, null);

    long rowid = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    return rowid;
}
```

here is how i access it

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            nameChanged = sqlName.getText().toString();
            numChanged = sqlNumber.getText().toString();
            GroupDb info = new GroupDb(EditDetails.this);
            info.open();
            long rowid = info.getRowId(name, num);
            info.updateNameNumber(rowid, nameChanged, numChanged);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rowid+" "+nameChanged+" "+numChanged, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ArrayList<Contact> searchResults = info.getView();
            MyCustomBaseAdapter mcba = new MyCustomBaseAdapter(EditDetails.this, searchResults);
            mcba.updateResults(searchResults);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            info.close();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> `public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`
>   [...]
>   **Returns**
>
> A `Cursor` object, which is positioned before the first entry.

So first you have step `c` into the result set and you can use [`moveToFirst`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) for that:

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

Now you need to extract the rowid from the row that the cursor is pointing at. But [`getColumnIndex`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) is for mapping a column name to a position in the row:

> Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist.

You're getting a zero from `getColumnIndex` because your `KEY_ROWID` is the first column in your SELECT query.

I think you're looking for [`getLong`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractWindowedCursor.html#getLong%28int%29) if you want to extract a `long` from the `Cursor`'s result set:

```
long rowid = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
```

If you know the structure of your query (which you do), you could skip the `getColumnIndex` call and just use the known index:

```
long rowid = c.getLong(0);
```

And if all you're doing is looking up the rowid, you can SELECT just `KEY_ROWID`:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID};
```

There's no need to pull things out of the database that you're ignoring.

Comment: so that's why i always get 0. thank you very much for your great explanation.